# How to save for a simple model I need to save the User key automatically How to get objects owned by a user? in Django

Tags: django

i have such a model

```
class Summaries(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    myfile = models.FileField(upload_to="document")

class Summary_Createes(models.Model):
    suser = models.ForeignKey(Summaries, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

for the active, current user
"Summary_Createes" The user who saved this model should only see it for himself
how can i filter such data i need filter

Comment: you may use django signals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Summary_Createes.objects.filter(suser__user=request.user)
```

Comment: thank you i am very grateful    Thank you + 10000000000000000000000000000000000000